# How to style the image within a react-image-lightbox?

Tags: reactjs, react-image-lightbox

Any suggestions on how to rotate the image in the react-image-lightbox - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-lightbox

Answer (score 0):

Use wrapperClassName on the Lightbox will do it...